# Cannot see button when placing UIView in front of Nav Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIView which has a button, I have added a round border around the button using UIView, the button works and is positioned perfectly, and I want the UIView in front of the navigation bar, but once I add the UIView in front of the navigation bar, the button disappears but the UIVew come in front of the navigation bar.

```
let viewBar = UIView()

let userProfileView = UIView()
let userProfileButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .red
    setupNextButton()
    setupViewBar()
    setupUserProfileButton()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // To Bring the viewBar in front of the navigation bar        
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(viewBar)
}

func setupViewBar() {

    viewBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)

    view.addSubview(viewBar)
    addNavigationBarConstraints()
}

func setupUserProfileButton() {

    userProfileButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profilePictureSmall.png"), for: .normal)
    userProfileButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    userProfileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profilePictureTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    userProfileView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    userProfileView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    userProfileView.clipsToBounds = true
    userProfileView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    userProfileView.addSubview(userProfileButton)

    //viewBar.addSubview(userProfileView)
    view.addSubview(userProfileView)
    addUserProfileButtonConstraints()

}
```

Here are the constraints to the user profile button and the viewBar

```
func addViewBarConstraints() {

    viewBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    viewBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    viewBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    viewBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

}

func addUserProfileButtonConstraints() {

    userProfileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    userProfileView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewBar.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    userProfileView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewBar.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
    userProfileView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    userProfileView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

}
```

How can I make the button appear? I have added some images too.

[image: UIView without navigation bar]

[image: UIView with (In front of) navigation bar]

Comment: Why you just don't add `userProfileButton` as `UIBarButtonItem` to `navigationItem`?

Comment: I'm not doing that cuz I want a top bar like the one in Snapchat, in snapchat, the left button in the top bar or navigation bar, doesn't change when you swipe left and right between view controllers, but the buttons on the right side of the top bar change form one view controller to another.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar goes on top of the stack of views and so it's hiding your red UIView. So, essentially, you have to add the button to the navigation bar instead of adding it to the UIView:

```
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: userProfileButton)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: This is a comment I made in reply to @vpoltave's comment. I'm not doing that cuz I want a top bar like the one in Snapchat, in snapchat, the left button in the top bar or navigation bar, doesn't change when you swipe left and right between view controllers, but the buttons on the right side of the top bar change form one view controller to another

Comment: Then don't use a navigation bar. Just implement buttons on your views to navigate.

Comment: I want one of the buttons to just stay in the view alyways, kinda like pinning an element the view. The other buttons should change when I swipe left or right.

Comment: You don't need a nav bar for this. Just add the same button to the different views. I'm pretty sure the snapshat app doesn't use a nav bar.